# Ubuntu 16.04 - Install PCI Hotplug Capability

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, pci, hotplug

I'm trying to achieve hotplugging of memory in KVM guests by following this tutorial: [Memory hotplug with Qemu/KVM and libvirt](https://medium.com/@juergen_thomann/memory-hotplug-with-qemu-kvm-and-libvirt-558f1c635972#.h6q46uw8m).

I managed to complete it but nothing happens. The tutorial tells me that I need kernel version 3.9 or higher, and I am running 4.8. It also states that I need modules `acpiphp` and `pci_hotplug`. Googling results told me that I just needed to run (on the guest):

```
for m in acpiphp pci_hotplug; do sudo modprobe ${m}; done
```

However, this results in the following erroneous output:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module acpiphp not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-39-generic
modprobe: FATAL: Module pci_hotplug not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-39-generic
```

This question seems similar to [Ask Ubuntu: PCI hotplug doesn't seem to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417443/pci-hotplug-doesnt-seem-to-work) where solution also states that I need acpiphp and pci_hotplug, so I'm pretty confident I need these modules.

### Question

How do I install `acpiphp` and `pci_hotplug` on an Ubuntu 16.04 for my KVM guest?

Answer (score 3):

Probably, that feature is already compiled in the kernel and you don't need to load any module. Check that these options are enabled in your kernel:

```
# grep "CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=" /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI=y

# grep "CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI=" /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=y

# grep "CONFIG_MEMORY_HOTPLUG=" /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_MEMORY_HOTPLUG=y
```

Then, for kernel >=4.8, you need to set this parameter on boot:

```
memhp_default_state=online
```

(as stated in the Proxmox Hotplug instructions)

Edit: if `memhp_default_state=` is not set on boot, kernel will default to `CONFIG_MEMORY_HOTPLUG_DEFAULT_ONLINE` kernel config.